# Access current user from viewsets.ViewSet

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

I am trying to access current user from List method in `viewsets.ViewSet`. But I am getting AnonymousUser.

I have tried this

```py
class ReportViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    """Shows purchase report group by day"""

    def list(self, request, **kwargs):
        print(self.request.user)
```

Is there any way to access current user from `viewsets.ViewSet`?

Comment: There is simply no logged in user. `AnonymousUser` means the client that made the request has not logged in.

Comment: Sir, actually I was logged in. It probably couldn't detect, because I didn't give authentication_classes before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved

```py
from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication

class ReportViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    """Shows purchase report group by day"""

    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)


    def list(self, request, **kwargs):
        print(self.request.user)
```